# May the integral $\int\root 3 \of{\cos(x)^2}\,dx$ be expressible by elementary functions?

Tags: integration, differential-algebra

I would like to decide by methods of differential algebra whether the integral $\int\root 3 \of{\cos(x)^2}\,dx$ might be contrary to the output of CAS Mathematica Online Integrator expressible by elementary functions and if not - why.  
Alas I have not the deep knowledge of the subject to be able to tackle this question without months of ( maybe fruitless ) study.  
I read about the Risch algorithm which might give the answer and already tried to integrate with the CAS Axiom which was said to have implemented the algorithm.  
Also I browsed an article of Bronstein but I presently dont understand the hard stuff.

Comment: Do you want to apply [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) to this particular example ?

Comment: I dont know whether/how Liouville theorem can be applied here. Maybe the method of Bronstein in his Symbolic Integration Tutorial shows a way - there he has a Transcendental tan example... (?). But at this moment I dont grasp it fully.

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram-Alpha gives a [closed form](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20cos%5E(2%2F3)%20x) solution to your indefinite integral:

$$-\frac{3}{5} \cos^{5/3}(x)\space_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{5}{6};\frac{11}{6};\cos^2 x\right)$$

Where $_2F_1$ is an example of a hypergeometric function.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know how to gain that result.

Comment: I dont either. If I go on like that I at least become expert in difficult questions LOL.